# List of lists with various lengths and items - change numbers

Tags: list, indexing

So my problem, to which I have been searching a solution for hours now, is, that I have a list of list with lists of various lengths and different items:

```
list_1=[[160,137,99,81,78,60],[132,131,131,127,124,123],'none',[99,95,80,78]]
```

Now I want to change the fifth number of every list and add +1. My problem is, that I keep getting 'out of range' or other problems, because list 3 doesn't contain numbers and list 3+4 don't contain a fifth element.

I have so far found no answer to this. My first guess was adding zeros to the lists, but I'm not supposed to do that. It would also falsify the results, since then it would add +1 to any zero I have created.

Comment: What language is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fix the previous post, and make minor correction,  try it and ask any questions:

Any function should *return* the modified list, otherwise, you will not get it (unless it's supposed to do *in-place c*hanges)

You may try do List Comprehension as well, but that's more involved.

```py
L =[[160,137,99,81,78,60],[132,131,131,127,124,123], None,[99,95,80,78]]

def addOne(L):
    for lst in L:
         if isinstance(lst, list) and len(lst) >= 5:
             lst[4] += 1
    return L
           
print(addOne(L))
```

Output:

```
[[160, 137, 99, 81, 79, 60], [132, 131, 131, 127, 125, 123], None, [99, 95, 80, 78]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel, this worked. Now I just have an additional question. I ran this several times, just to see, and it added another +1 every time I ran it, so I had to reset the values. How would I change this so it would always use the defined L as input , meaning it would always add +1 to the same original input and not get increasingly higher?

Comment: Glad it can help.  You could you *copy.deepcopy(L)* to make a new List copy, so that the change will not affect the original list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is in Python,

```
list_1=[[160,137,99,81,78,60],[132,131,131,127,124,123],'none',[99,95,80,78]]

def addOneToFifthElement(theList):
    for list_ in theList:
         if type(list_)=="<class 'list'>" and len(list_)>=5:
             list_[4] += 1

addOneToFifthElement(list_1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ran this, but the output still remains the same. I tried various different methods, but every time I still got the original list - can you tell me how to get the correct output?

list_1=[[160,137,99,81,78,60],[132,131,131,127,124,123],'none',[99,95,80,78]]
​
def addOneToFifthElement(theList):
    for list_ in theList:
         if type(list_)=="<class 'list'>" and len(list_)>=5:
             list_[4] += 1
​
addOneToFifthElement(list_1)
list_1
[[160, 137, 99, 81, 78, 60],
 [132, 131, 131, 127, 124, 123],
 'none',
 [99, 95, 80, 78]]

Comment: Just make the function to return the list.